# PHP Copy Paste Detector on Ubuntu machine

Tags: php, ubuntu, pear

I want to install PHP Copy Paste Detector on Ubuntu machine, for this I used that command:-

```
    sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
```

that is run scussfully, but when I try that command:-

```
   sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/phpcpd
```

this is showing error message
error is :-

```
   No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/phpcpd"
   install failed
```

I tried many command for this like:-

```
  pear config-set auto_discover 1
  pear install --force --alldeps pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools
  sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
  pear clear-cache  etc. but one help full for me.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian Bergmann, author of phpunit, switched off phpunit's pear channel some time ago rendering your efforts useless.

You now need to use either the .phar or install phpcpd via composer instead - details are here at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd